# How do I build a metawriter bean for Alfresco?

Tags: java, spring, metadata, alfresco

I'm reading the short (3 page) Metadata writer user's guide and am left confused.  Clearly I need to build a Spring bean with my mappings and link it with the document type.  Doesn't seem to be any more specific information out on the web though.

- Where do I put the Spring bean that I've built?
- How do I tell the system to differentiate types of document/beans (example, if I have different documents that need different beans, how do I split up the access?).

Comment: For the last part, it's normally done by mime type. For the first part, did you try following guides for metadata extractors? The Metadata Writers are largely the inverse of those

Comment: I'll go lookup Metadata Extractors.  I was unaware of them!

Comment: [This talk from several years ago](http://www.slideshare.net/alfresco/metadata-extraction-and-content-transformation) should still largely cover it, though it pre-dates the metadata writers which is why it doesn't feature them!

Comment: Hmmmm, the generalities are good, but I'm still missing the "make it go" technical level details.  Do I need to write my own AMP action for it, or does the metawriter module itself do the work?

Comment: Better yet, does anyone have an example (or tutorial) that details step by step on a simple metawriter implementation?

Comment: If you don't mind going through Apache Tika for your embedding, then there's the [Alfresco Tika ExifTool plugin](https://github.com/Alfresco/tika-exiftool/) which does it